# iOS Push a specific view when notification arrives

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification, pushviewcontroller

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running

    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);

    NSLog(@"local notifications count = %d", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);


    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"everything9", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RELOAD_DATA"object:nil];

}
```

What can I implement here to push a specific view when the application arrives (when the user slides the app icon when the iPhone is locked, for example)... I'm trying `[self.navigationController pushViewController:CompletedViewController animated:YES];` and I get some errors... Is there a specific way I should do it? Maybe in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type AppDelegate

Comment: Have you defined any navigation controller?and also what error you are getting?

Comment: Well, there you have it. The `AppDelegate` is not designed as a `UIViewController`. It has a `window` where you can and should put your `UIViewController`'s structure.

Comment: error because you haven't defined any navigation controller, you first need to define that.

Comment: So how exactly I would define a navigation controller inside the AppDelegate? is it possible? I'm new to iOS that's why the simple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you should call this

<strike>[_window.rootViewController pushViewController:CompletedViewController animated:YES];</strike>

The code above doesn't work now. You should try using this instead.

```
 //We take the rootViewController first which is expected to be a UINavigationController in your case
 UINavigationController *naviController = _window.rootViewController;  
 //We then call the push view controller code    
 [naviController pushViewController:CompletedViewController animated:YES];
```

this is how you push to your current navigation controller from the AppDelegate if you are using storyboards. Specially if your starting point on the story board is a navigation controller.

Comment: `No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated'`

Comment: It seems this code doesn't work now. You can try the code below and see if it works.
UINavigationController *naviController = _window.rootViewController;
[naviController pushViewController:CompletedViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/) will fit your needs. It will teach how to use a `UINavigationController` inside the `AppDelegate`. If you have further questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In the older versions of Xcode, We have an option while creating the applications is navigation based applications. But in the latest Xcode generations, we can create Single view based or window based applications. So, if you want to use the navigation controller properties, you need to create the instance for UINavigationController and need to set the rootViewController. The code is as follows,

appDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

appDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

So that, you can use navigation properties throughout the application.

I think this may helpful to you.

Comment: Just one little question. Im getting some errors on self.viewController. Should I put the name of a specific view controller that I want? Or it should work just like that? error: "property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'"

Comment: simply if you create a singleView based application, by default one UIViewController object is added to your application main window. Instead of adding that object, you need to make it as rootViewController for UINavigationController and need to add UINavigationController object to main window.

Comment: If you want to put the name of a specific view controller, you need to change the class reference in MainWindow.xib also.

Comment: I'm using storyboard and I already have a navigation controller, that's why I asked. The app is crashing, and its probably because 2 navigation controllers exists when I implement this. I needed to access the mainView navigation controller. I don't know if I was clear. Was I?

Comment: ya, that's clear Lucas. have you checked that does your application main window is having navigation controller properties or not?

Comment: Yes, it has by default when you implement it in the storyboard... in the main view, I just write self.navigationController and I can push where ever I want to. The problem is when i'm at the delegate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13040/discussion-between-lucas-vallim-da-costa-and-rajesh)

Answer (score 0):

"[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];”

**This can’t be used from AppDelegate.m (ie. from didReceiveLocalNotification).**

Try once by using “self.pushViewController” from didReceiveLocalNotification.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([EntNotStrApp isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    EntNotStrApp=@"0";

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController;

    DumpFeed *dump = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DumpFeed"];

    dump.isPushed=YES;

    dump.strUserId = appDelegate.strFriendid;


    [navController pushViewController:dump animated:YES];

}else
{
     [[iToast makeText:NotMess] show];
}
```